# GTK+3: How to render INSENSITIVE widgets in the style of NORMAL widgets

Tags: python, gtk3

Sorry if this is a repost, I just can't find the answer anywhere.  I am developing an application in Python and GTK+3 which has a TreeView which is set to be INSENSITIVE.  This prohibits our users from making direct selections on a table of constants.   The default behaviour of INSENSITIVE GTK+3 widgets however is to shade an insensitive object.  In most cases this is a good behaviour, but in my case I need my table to remain easily legible.

What I would like to do is to be able to override the rendering of this particular INSENSITIVE object to match the rendering of NORMAL objects.  Then if the user changes GTK themes, this particular INSENSITIVE widget will be rendered just like the normal widgets.

I am attaching some simple code to illustrate my point ...

```
import gi.repository.Gtk as Gtk
import gi.repository.Gdk as Gdk

class Example(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        """A minimal example of the rendering of a INSENSITIVE widget"""

        # Use Gtk.Window __init__ method
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        # Add a box
        self.set_title("Example1")
        self.box = Gtk.Box()
        self.add( self.box )

        # Entry widget
        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry.set_text("Can't touch this")
        self.entry.set_sensitive( False )
        self.box.pack_start(self.entry, True, True, 0)


class Example2(Example):

    def __init__(self):
        """Forced recoloring of the INSENSITIVE widget.  How do I do
        this so that it matches the GTK 3+ style for normal text?
        """

        # Use Example __init__ method
        Example.__init__(self)
        self.set_title("Example2")

        # Hack the color
        self.entry.override_color(
            Gtk.StateFlags.INSENSITIVE,
            Gdk.RGBA(0,0,0,1)
            )

        self.entry.override_background_color(
            Gtk.StateFlags.INSENSITIVE,
            Gdk.RGBA(1,1,1,1)
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Example 1
    Window1 = Example()
    Window1.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    Window1.show_all()

    # Example 2
    Window2 = Example2()
    Window2.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Here I overwrote the colouring of Example2.  How can I overwrite it in a way that will always match the GTK theme?

Answer (score 1):

You can access a widget's style properties from it's [GtkStyleContext](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkStyleContext.html), which you can obtain by calling the `get_style_context` method of any widget. With the instance of the context you can access the different style properties using the corresponding [GtkStateFlag](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk3-Standard-Enumerations.html#GtkStateFlags).

Here is an example of how to get the background color of the widget when it's on `NORMAL` state:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

def get_background_color(widget):
    context = widget.get_style_context()
    color = context.get_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)

    return color # the result is a GdkRGBA instance
```

I'm not completely sure what you should do to completly overwrite the `INSENSITIVE` state's styles, but I'm guessing you should use a [GtkStyleProvider](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkStyleProvider.html).

Comment: This is actually deprecated as of newer releases of GTK, because CSS does not have a "background color", only a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try another approach, such as setting `treeview.props.reorderable = False` and setting all the cell renderer modes to `INERT`?